# How can I use the 'newline' keyword argument for 'open' in 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I tried this code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
#Use request for tokens
import requests
import json

def write_csv2(filename, table):
    with open(filename, 'w', newline = '') as csvfile:
        out_csv = csv.writer(csvfile)
        out_csv.writerows(table)
```

but I get an exception saying that 'newline' is an invalid keyword. Does this not work in Python 2.7? How can I specify the newline character when opening a file in text mode?

Comment: Isn't that a Python 3 thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 2.x, the [`io`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html) standard library module provides the same interface for accessing files and streams that is the default in Python 3.x. Try using [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open), which supports the `newline` keyword argument:

```
>>> import io
>>> with io.open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
...     out_csv = csv.writer(csvfile)
...     out_csv.writerows(table)
```